# Why is clang-tidy produces "narrowing conversion" for this C99 program?

Tags: c, type-conversion, c99, clang-tidy

Why does the 2nd and 3rd assignments in `f2` produces this and the first doesn't?

`Clang-Tidy: Narrowing conversion from 'int' to signed type 'char' is implementation-defined`

AFAIK, according to C language specification the type of the ternary operator result is determined by the type of the first return clause, ergo, the type of `X ? Y : Z` is the type of `Y`, so the type of `test() ? f1() : 'b'` and `test() ? 'b' : f1()` should be char.

However, the third line doesn't produce this warning, so apparently clang-tidy thinks that the type of `test() ? f1() : 'b'` is `int`...

```c
int a;
int test() { return a; }
char f1() { return 'x'; }

void f2() {
    char x = f1(); // fine
    char y = test() ? f1() : 'b'; // clang-tidy "narrowing conversion"
    char z = test() ? 'b' : f1(); // clang-tidy "narrowing conversion"
    char w = (char) (test() ? f1() : 'b'); // fine
}
```

P.S. please don't refer me to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60912937/narrowing-conversion). There is no relation.

Comment: Please be aware that character constant `'b'` is of type `int`.

Comment: Please try `printf("%zu", sizeof 'b');`

Comment: @traveh: In C, the type of a plain character constant is `int`, not `char`, per C 1999 6.4.4.4 10 and C 2018 6.4.4.4 10.

Comment: So this was changed from C90? I remember a character literal used to be of type `char`.

Comment: @WeatherVane My apologies ... I guess I'm quite outdated...

Comment: C89/90 section **6.1.3.4 Character constants** says *"An integer character constant has type `int`"* and *"If an integer character constant contains a single character or escape sequence. its value is the one that results when an object with type `char` whose value is that of the single character or escape sequence is converted to type `int`."*

Comment: @traveh - You might have looked at C++ rules, where in fact `'b'` has type `char` (to allow for overloaded functions).

Comment: @BoP you might be right. I remember it being *somewhere* :o

Answer (score 1):

> AFAIK, according to C language specification the type of the ternary operator result is determined by the type of the first return clause…

It is not. C 1999 6.5.15 5 says:

> If both the second and third operands have arithmetic type, the result type that would be determined by the usual arithmetic conversions, were they applied to those two operands, is the type of the result…

In ordinary C implementations, the common type of the usual arithmetic conversions applied to `char` and `int` is `int`.

> However, the third line doesn't produce this warning, so apparently clang-tidy thinks that the type of `test() ? f1() : 'b'` is `int`...

The result type of all the conditional operator expressions shown is `int`. The reason `clang-tidy` does not warn about it is not because of the types involved but because that statement contains a cast. Code analyzers commonly take a `cast` as a deliberate conversion the author has thought about, and they do not warn about deliberate conversions as much as with implicit conversions such as occur in an assignment.

Comment: Note that I was asking about C99 (although it might not change the answer, the quote is wrong).

Comment: @traveh: The text is exactly the same in C 2018, including the clause and paragraph numbers.

Comment: Got it. Strange though that `(char)'A' + (char)'A')` produces an `int`...

Comment: @traveh: `+` uses the usual arithmetic conversions too, and the usual arithmetic conversions for `char` and `char` result in `int`, because integer types narrower than `int` are automatically promoted to `int` (with some technicalities). Most integer arithmetic in C is done as `int` or wider.

Answer (score 1):

The following have no narrowing as it is `char_object = some_char_value;`

```
char x = f1(); // fine
char w = (char) (test() ? f1() : 'b'); // fine
```

---

With `:?`, the return type is a common type between `char` and `int`, which in OP's implementation is an `int`.  Note that `'b'`, a *character constant*, has type `int`.

```
char y = test() ? f1() : 'b'; // clang-tidy "narrowing conversion"
char z = test() ? 'b' : f1(); // clang-tidy "narrowing conversion"
```

This is like `char_object = some_int_value;`.  As the `int` range exceeds `char`, there is, in general, a narrowing potential.

---

Consider a 5th case: `char_object = a_particular_int_value;`.  Here the compiler knows the `int` value is in range of a `char` and does not emit a warning.

```
char v = 'b';
```

With more advanced compiler analysis, a compiler could recognize that `char y = test() ? f1() : 'b'` also does not attempt to assign an out-of-range `char` value and so not warn.

---

> I remember a character literal used to be of type `char`.

C defines `'b'` as a *character-constant* of type `int`, not as a *character literal*.

C defines only 2 literals: *string literals* and *compound literals*.

I suspect OP is thinking of C++ which does use character literal and there `'b'` is type `char`.